# Clion doesn't see Mingw

Tags: c++, c, ide, clion

Clion doesn't see path folder mingw/bin despite the fact that ATOM ide sees and works with
[image]

Comment: Does `zlib1.dll` exist? Clion says it does not exist and that is the issue. I have that file in my mingw binary folder   but I don't use CLion. I use the mingw provided from msys2 which uses gcc-11

Comment: i have checked it,it is inside bin but Clion doesn't see.I can run my code in atom.if it weren't there atom wouldn't work either.

Comment: Does it works if you will try to use `C:\MinGW` path?